# installing chaco [anaconda] UnsatisfiableError conflict chaco mkl_fft

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I want to install chaco by anaconda,
I got the following results :

```
conda install -c anaconda chaco
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - chaco
  - mkl_fft
```

enable is a dependency of chaco,

```
conda install -c anaconda enable
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - enable
  - mkl_fft
```

I have already installed `mkl_fft`.
I am new to using anaconda. 
Do you have any solution?
regards